# Django 1.2 and south problem

Tags: django, django-south

I was using python 2.5 and django 1.0.2. But I moved to python 2.6 and django 1.2 recently and I'm getting the following error now during the migrate:

```
alex@alex-desktop:~/server/mx30$ python manage.py migrate
Running migrations for peer_center:
 - Migrating forwards to 0005_adding_config_model.
 > peer_center: 0001_initial
 > peer_center: 0002_add_cache
 > peer_center: 0003_add_options_field
 > peer_center: 0004_add_player_option_to_media_item
 > peer_center: 0005_adding_config_model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 195, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 91, in handle
    skip = skip,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/south/migration.py", line 586, in migrate_app
    db.send_pending_create_signals()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 678, in send_pending_create_signals
    self.really_send_create_signal(app_label, list(set(model_names)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 718, in really_send_create_signal
    verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 166, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/management.py", line 10, in update_contenttypes
    db = kwargs['db']
KeyError: 'db'
```

After running migrate several times, it eventually passes. 
I have 5 different apps under migration and I thought it can be dependencies issue. But I have no migrations calling other apps.
So what can be the problem?

Regards, Arshavski Alexander.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django 1.2 supports multiple DB's, and the version of South you are running does not. Try checking out a more recent version - supposedly this was [fixed at some point in 0.6](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/335), and should work in 0.7.